# Google chart: "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string" eror

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to display a line chart of currency rates via [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart).

Basically i have 2 type of values:

1. Date (format iso8601)
2. Rate (decimal number)

when i'm trying to render the chart i get an error: "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"

Here is my code:

PHP array making:

```
        $xml=simplexml_load_file('https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/ils.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $arrayForChart = array();
    $arrayForChart["Date"] = "Rate";
    foreach ($xml->DataSet->Series->Obs as $key => $value) {
        $dateIso8601Format=$value['TIME_PERIOD'];
        $rateForDate=(string)$value['OBS_VALUE'][0];
        $arrayForChart["$dateIso8601Format"] = $rateForDate;
    }
    $arrayForChart = json_encode($arrayForChart);
```

Javascript

```
var arrayForChart;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxUrl,
    //data: {configuration: Config },
    success: function (data) {

        arrayForChart = data;
        arrayForChart = $.map(arrayForChart, function (el) {
            return el;
        });//converting js object to js array

    },
    cache: false
});
google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart", "line"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);

function drawLineColors() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([arrayForChart]);

    var options = {
        hAxis: {
            title: "Rate",
            id: "Rate",
            label: "Rate",
            type: "number"
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: "Date",
            id: "Date",
            label: "Date",
            type: "string"
        },
        colors: ["#a52714", "#097138"]
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Sample of data:

```
["Rate","4.7278","4.7301","4.6814"]
```

Anybody might know what is the problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: please share a sample of the data --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayForChart));`

Comment: added sample of the dara. thanks!

Comment: Try converting the value you've used to `$rateForDate` using `(float)$rateForDate`

Comment: converted rates to float. still not working.data sample: ["Rate",4.7278,4.7301,4.6814]  .i ge this error t: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown header type: 4.7278
    at https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.1/js/jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:81:258
    at Array.map (native)...

Comment: for a line chart, there should be at least two columns of data --> `[["Date", "Rate"],["2017-07-03", 4.7278],["2017-07-04", 4.7301]]`

Comment: thanks! that worked for this error. but now i have another error. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44914500/google-chart-uncaught-in-promise-error-unknown-header-type-4-7278-error